# Aurelia dash in component name not working

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a basic Aurelia component and it looks like when I use dash in it's name, it doesn't work.

It works when I have it like this:

```
import {inject, customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('helloworld')
@inject(Element)
export class HelloWorldCustomElement {
    constructor(element) {
        console.log ('here')
    }
}
```

```
<helloworld></helloworld>
```

But it doesn't when is like this:

```
import {inject, customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('hello-world')
@inject(Element)
export class HelloWorldCustomElement {
    constructor(element) {
        console.log ('here')
    }
}
```

```
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

According to the Aurelia docs, it should work both ways: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/doc/article/en-US/templating-custom-elements.md

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another `hello-world` component or property in your applicaton?

Comment: This appears to be the case. I was importing an HTML file with the same name which was causing a conflict: `<require from="hello-world/hello-world.html"></require>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the cause for this. In `app.html` I had the following line and it appears that there was a naming conflict. Removing it fixed the problem right away.

```
<require from="hello-world/hello-world.html"></require>
```

Comment: Also worth noting that you don't need to use the `customElement` decorator if you're using the default naming convention via `MyElementCustomElement` and vice-versa. The decorator gives you more control and allows you to have a differently named class to the element.